# Is $U(pq)$ a cyclic group, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$U(pq)$ is to be the units of $Z_{pq}$. I would assume that distinct prime factors would enable $U(pq)$ to always by cyclic. My professor alluded to the fact that this may not always be true. However, I am curious if this is always the case, since $U(p)$ is cyclic, given $p$ is prime.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: When $p$ is prime, $U(p)$ is indeed a cyclic group—but of order $p-1$, not $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $U(15)=U(3×5)$ were cyclic, there would be a primitive root modulo $15$, but there is none. Thus $U(15)$ is not cyclic.

$U(n)$ is cyclic iff $n=1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $k\ge1$.

Comment: So is there a way to prove that $U(n)$ is always cyclic if we can write $n$ as $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ with $k$ distinct primes? Or is this, by your argument, also never cyclic?

Comment: @Edison See the duplicate.